# adding a padding to divider in compose does not work

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have added a divider in compose and I am trying to set a padding to it, I want the divider to start 100dp from left (start) and 100dp from right(end), but I see a light grey line still visible. how can make the divider work please without using constraints

code of divider

`Divider(color = Color.LightGray, thickness = 1.dp, modifier = Modifier.padding( start = 106.dp, end = 106.dp ) )`

here is a screen shot if what I see

[image]

Comment: Adding padding to the modifier should work. Is the gray at the end the background color?

Comment: Hello @Abhimanyu thank you for coming back, you said adding padding to the modifier, I have added padding to the modifier like this modifier = Modifier.padding( start = 106.dp, end = 106.dp , could you please let me know what you were reffering to please

Comment: Yes, your exact code works for me. You can inspect the layout to see where the other gray is from.